# does anyone know how history mapper works in python?

Tags: python-3.x, sqlalchemy, history, mapper

does anyone know how history mapper works in python?
Why are NOT all fields of the main table written to the history table?

example:

```
class TableNameOrm(DbNameMetaBase, MixinLocked, MixinCreatedAt, Versioned):
    __tablename__ = 'table_name'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True, autoincrement=True)
    title = Column(String(80), nullable=False)
    image_type_code = Column(String(100), nullable=True)  
TableNameHistoryOrm = TableNameOrm.__history_mapper__.class\_
```

when you update table TableNameOrm, all fields except image_type_code are written to history table TableNameHistoryOrm, it writes null.
What should I do so that image_type_code is also updated in the history?

Answer (score 0):

In short, the project had routers to another project, which updated the history table by events